# Does Hibernate HQL support aliasing subqueries?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, hql

I'm using Hibernate 3.2.6 and I'm attempting to make a query like so:

```
select 
    a, 
    (select min(date) as someAlias from B b where a.id = b.id)
from A a
    where someAlias is not null and someAlias between :start and :end
```

Imagine that this query makes sense in the context that I'm operating in. When I run this query, I get an error saying "Unknown column 'someAlias' in 'where clause'". When I show the SQL output, I see that SQL doesn't seem to include the 'as someAlias' part of the query.

Is this just unsupported, or am I missing something? Or this just a feature not supported in version of Hibernate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translate the query to native sql and fire it on db, it will not work.It is not a valid query because aliases in select clause will not be visible in where clause.

Aliases are supported in HQL.

Comment: This makes sense. I'm used to having my subqueries in the join or from clause, where it is possible to set an alias. Of course, HQL doesn't support subqueries there, so I'm back to square 1 with this query, but thank you for answering the question.